# Python Check Duplicate in Array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

i want check content if MyNewFile in myList. its my code, but it wont so good.

```
myList=[{"text": "1"},{"text": "2"},{"text": "3"},{"text": "4"},{"text": "5"},{"text": "6"}]
myNewFile=[{"text": "10"},{"text": "5"},{"text": "7"},{"text": "8"}]

for index in range(len(myNewFile)):
    if (myList[index]["text"]==myNewFile[index]["text"]):
        print "same"
    else:
        print "input"
```

final result:

its have one same value (both have text = "5"). any sugestion? thanks

Comment: Is this your actual code? `len(myFile)` should give you a NameError because `myFile` doesn't exist.

Comment: are the keys always the same? could you put the values, or items, in a set and use set operations?

Comment: Your code checks if 2 entries **with the same index** are the same.  If the length of myFile is too big, then you will get out-of-range issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to convert both of the lists to sets and then do set intersection.

1. For every dictionary in the list, get the `items()` list and pass each of those elements to `set` function.

   ```
   set1 = set(item for d in myList for item in d.items())
   set2 = set(item for d in myNewList for item in d.items())
   ```

At this point the sets look like this

```
set([('text', '5'), ('text', '4'), ('text', '6'), ('text', '1'), ('text', '3'), ('text', '2')])
set([('text', '7'), ('text', '10'), ('text', '5'), ('text', '8')])
```

2. Then simply do intersection with `&` operator, and reconstruct the original dictionary with dictionary comprehension, like this

   ```
   print {item[0]:item[1] for item in set1 & set2}
   # {'text': '5'}
   ```

Comment: Using `set1.intersection(set2)` should be more readable than `&`.